# If $L=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{p=1}^m \frac{p}{2p+m+m^2}$, then find floor(L).

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

> If $L=\displaystyle\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{p=1}^m \frac{p}{2p+m+m^2}$, then find floor(L).

This is from a preparatory examination for the college entrance exams for high-school students. 
I first tried to convert it into a definite integral by the conventional way, but the $m^2$ term kept interfering. Now the only other thing that I could think of was the sandwich theorem or the squeeze theorem, for which also I could think about only the upper bound. This was $$L\leq \lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{p=1}^m \frac{p}{2p+m}= \int_0^1\frac{xdx}{2x+1}=\frac{2-\ln 3}{4}$$ while this gives me the correct value of the floor function, but the solution claims that $L=\frac 12$.

Comment: Are you familiar with harmonic numbers ?

Comment: No. You mean the partial harmonic sums which involve the Euler-Mascheroni constant? I only know the name and have read about them in popular books for non math readers.

Comment: Please include in your post, the source of your question?

Comment: It’s Done :  @amWhy

Comment: Thanks, insipid! I appreciate it.

Comment: @amWhy Would you recommend using displaystyle every time instead of \frac, \tfrac, or \dfrac? Or are there specific instances where those might be better?

Comment: Not always, but in this case, it helps to align left.  It also shows the the $m\to \infty$ under the summation side, which we don't encourage in titles.  I've never used \tfrac, but sometimes use \dfrac.  Given the limit and the frac, I merely used \displaystyle to cover both.  Good questions.

Comment: What do you mean floor(L)?

Comment: The greatest integer function, i.e. the greatest integer less than or equal to L. @xpaul

Comment: You claim $L=\frac12$. So you want to show $\lfloor L\rfloor=0$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. It would be best if you could find the exact value of L,  but I’ll take [L]=0 if it has greater clarity than what I have already done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that:

$$ \sum_{p=1}^{m} \frac{p}{{\color{Red}{2m}}+m+m^2} \leq \sum_{p=1}^{m} \frac{p}{{\color{Red}{2p}}+m+m^2} \leq \sum_{p=1}^{m} \frac{p}{{\color{Red}{1}}+m+m^2}$$

$$\frac{m(m+1)}{2(2m+m+m^2)} \leq \sum_{p=1}^{m} \frac{p}{2p+m+m^2} \leq \frac{m(m+1)}{2(1+m+m^2)} $$

As $m \to \infty$, the sum tends to $\dfrac 12$.

Comment: +1 for highlighting the important part in red

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea.
$$
\sum_{p=1}^m \frac{p}{2p+m+m^2}=\sum_p\frac{p/m}{2(p/m)+1+m}=\sum_p\frac{p/m}{m(\frac{2(p/m)+1}{m}+1)}=\\\sum_p\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{m}(-1)^k p/m(2p/m+1)^k\times \frac{1}{m^k}
$$
I don't know how rigorous you have to be but you can exchange both sums and take the limit term by term. then without the $\frac{1}{m^k}$ the $p$-sum converges to an integral.
$$
\int_0^1dt \, t(2t+1)^k<3^k
$$
Hence the $k$-th term goes as $3^k/m^k\to 0$ for $k>0$ so you only have to take care of the term of the $k=0$ term. This one gives $\int_0^1 t=1/2$.

The problem with your solution is that
$$
\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{p=1}^m\frac{p}{2p+m}\neq \lim_{m\to \infty}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{p=1}^m\frac{p/m}{2p/m+1}=\int_0^1\frac{t}{2t+1}dt
$$

Comment: Ohh…how convenient of me to forget the 1/m outside! Thank you!  But your answer is A bit too technical for me. But +1 for the mistake being pointed out.